# How can I remove an element of my website using media queries

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to remove this:

```
<div id="mail1">
  <li>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <a href="mailto:support@mywebsite.com.au">support@mywebsite.com.au</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

When a device is smaller than 600px.

Comment: Set `display: none` for id `mail1`

Comment: @MirentafazAli that would hide the element for all screen sizes.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell I meant for smaller screen only(600px).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a class instead of assigning the property to an id. This will help you use this class to multiple components which you want to hide on a screen having width less than 600px.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktop-only {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mail1" class="desktop-only"><li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="mailto:support@mywebsite.com.au">support@mywebsite.com.au</a></li></div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution and my personal recommendation for most cases. Assuming 600px will also stand as your primary mobile breakpoint, setting up hide-mobile/desktop-only and hide-desktop/mobile-only classes will really streamline your styling. This utility-first mindset is the backbone of many CSS frameworks, especially Tailwind CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use media query and then use display none.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #mail1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see most answers on here using `max-width: 600px` but if you truly want to hide it **under** 600px, you should use `599px` like this:

#### Desktop-First CSS

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  #mail1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

If you want to use mobile-first CSS, you can code it like this instead:

#### Mobile-First CSS

```css
#mail1 {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #mail1 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```